# Hermitian scalar product: When is it invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices, hermitian-matrices

I know that positive definite symmetric matrices (in euclidean vector spaces) are always invertible.
Are positive definite symmetric **hermitian** matrices always invertible (in an hermitian vector space) as well? 
I don't know how to be sure and I can't prove it. Help?

I'm supposing $V$ is an hermitian vector space, $v$ is a vector in $V$ and $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ hermitian scalar product. Given any $v$ in $V$, $\langle  v, v  \rangle$ is real, so my definition of "positive definite" is:

$$ \langle  v, v  \rangle  > 0$$

for all non-zero $v$ in $V$ and

$$ \langle v, v \rangle = 0$$

iff $v=0$.

Comment: What is the definition of positive definite that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition should say $\langle v,\,v\rangle\ge0$ for $v\in V$, with equality iff $v=0$. To prove invertibility, note the matrix's eigenvalues must be positive.

Comment: right I forgot to write it. second part: why?

Comment: @user735782 A Hermitian matrix's eigenvalues are real. The proof that the above constraint on $\langle\cdot,\,\cdot\rangle$ implies they're positive is the same as in the symmetric-matrix case with which you're familiar.